# How to clear textfield entityreference_autofill if select -none-

Tags: 7

How to clear textfiled from module [Entity reference autofill](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_autofill).

If select ***-none-***, I try with jquery but not respond if change to ***-none-***.